# Installing LED Strip Lights

Tags: lighting, led

Re:50cm 9W 5630 SMD 36 LED Cabinet Light DC 12V

I have recently brought the above strip lights.
Can someone please advise me which drivers I need to order to:
a) Power 3 of the above
b) Power 2 of the above
c) Power 1 of the above
Many thanks Colin

Answer (score 1):

You need a power supply which provides 12 volts DC. Given a sensible margin for safety and expansion, I would go with a

- 15 watt unit for 1 light
- 30 watt unit for 2 lights
- 45 watt unit for 3 lights.

The main thing is making sure the power supply unit is legal to connect in bousehold wiring, depending on how power is being supplied to it.  It might be a unit that bolts into a 1/2" knockout, or mounts on a junction box faceplate, etc.